# Custom location for the "installation symlink" of a systemd unit file?

Tags: systemd

Enabling a systemd service to start at boot is done by `enabling` it.
Enabling creates a symlink at a specific location.
Example:

```
$ systemctl enable rsyslog                                                       
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rsyslog.service → /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service.
```

The documentation for [`systemctl enable`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#enable%20UNIT%E2%80%A6) states:

> Note that this operation creates only the symlinks suggested in the "[Install]" section of the unit files.

I would like to change the location where these symlinks are created (and checked for) for a particular service.

Is it possible to have set this location to something else?

Once the change I'm asking about is implemented the behavior would be:

```
$ systemctl enable rsyslog                                                       
Created symlink /user/home/multi-user.target.wants/rsyslog.service → /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service.
```

---

<sup>The use case from which this question originates is to have the status of the service (enabled/disabled) survive a full rewrite of the rootfs (embedded system update) by having the links living on a separate partition.</sup>

Comment: Have you read about systemctl link?

Comment: @MarkStosberg That is about the unit file being in a custom location. My question is about the location where the symlink is created when enabled.

Answer (score 0):

No. The search path for unit files is documented in [man systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

For user units you could customize $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, but for system units the paths are fixed.